# Convert all non-printable characters to space

Tags: regex, vb.net

This one is a little tricky.

I want to convert all non-printable characters to space or chr(32).

But if there are multiple and consecutive none printable characters, then I want a single space returned.

This is what I have so far, but I can't make it work

```
Regex.Replace(Mystring , "\p{Cc}", Function(a) String.Format("[{0:X2}]", CByte(a.Value(0))))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use something simpler, a bit like this:

```
Regex.Replace(Mystring , "\p{Cc}+", " ")
```

[ideone demo](http://ideone.com/bXeLY0)

This will replace any character that matches `\p{Cc}` (and consecutive ones if any) by a single space character.

Answer (score 1):

Use `+` with your regex which means `1 or more`.

```
\p{Cc}+
```